# JavaFX automatically resize Button's font size to fit in

Tags: java, css, javafx, font-size

I am programming a JavFX UI on Java 8 where I create Buttons with sizes calculated at construction time.

The problem is that the button's text (usually just a single letter in my case) sometimes is too big to fit in the button and then the button just stays blank.

How can I set the font size for a JavaFX Button so that the text is not too high to not get displayed?

Comment: Just a note: If you are on Java 8, then you are programming for JavaFX 8 as well...

Comment: We need your JavaFX code. I can only assume you are using absolute sizes that you calculate yourself, in which case you should get started with dynamic layouts.

Comment: @RAnders00 I assign the button a static size (e.g. `button.setMinSize(70, 70)`. The font size was defined using a CSS file that said e.g. `-fx-font-size: 20pt` for that button. This worked, but now I need to add buttons of other sizes and automatically adjusting fonts.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. It's probably not very beautiful and I have no idea where the `0.45` come from (found it by trying), but it seems to work for me:

```
int buttonSize = 70; 
Button button = new Button("A");
button.setMinSize(buttonSize, buttonSize);
button.setPrefSize(buttonSize, buttonSize);
button.setMaxSize(buttonSize, buttonSize);

button.setStyle(String.format("-fx-font-size: %dpx;", (int)(0.45 * buttonSize)));
```

The last line calculates the font height in `px` units and sets it as style for this button.